# Understanding scipy.stats.norm.rvs()?

Tags: python

In `scipy.stats.norm.rvs()` the argument scale denotes standard deviation but in the below piece of code sigma_list refers to an array. How does the code actually work?

Where sigma_list is obtained by following code:

```
sigma=0.06

mask=(x > 0.65) & (x < 0.8)

sigma_list=sigma+mask*0.03

sigma_list

y = sp.stats.norm.rvs(scale=sigma_list, size=200)
```

Even the standard deviations of both sigma_list and y are also not matching

I want to know the working of the above scipy module

sorry, i didn't mention that x is an array of values between 0 and 1

Comment: Some code is missing for `x`.

Comment: The standard deviation of `sigma_list` and `y` are different because your sample is small. Set for example `size = 20000` and `std(y)` will be close to `sigma_list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the `mask` will be either True or False here. So if you do some addition or subtraction, it is respectively translated into 1 or 0.

Then the result of `sigma_list` is not a list nor an array but a floating value. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html), you can see its usage.

```
rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=1, random_state=None)
```

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2771) (line 2771) you have:

> loc : array_like, optional
>               Location parameter (default=0).
>
> size : int or tuple of ints, optional
>               Defining number of random variates (Default is 1).  Note that `size`
>               has to be given as keyword, not as positional argument.
>
> random_state : None or int or `np.random.RandomState` instance, optional
>               If int or RandomState, use it for drawing the random variates.
>               If None, rely on `self.random_state`.
>               Default is None.

Comment: This is only true for x being a scalar.

Comment: @MaxPowers `>>> x = 0.7
>>> mask=(x > 0.65) & (x < 0.8)
>>> mask
True`

Comment: Yes. `x` is a scalar in your example. If `x` was an array, the above expression would return an array of bools, which would cause `.rvs()` to throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. I did not understood it like that.

Comment: x is an array,i forgot to mention

Comment: Well from the source of the function it won't work then. I suggest you iterate over the list instead if you want several samples each of the same size but with different variance.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have created a variable called `x`. The size of this variable should be 200, since this is the size of the generated random variable `y`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
```

Then the `mask` is selecting every sample of `x` that is greater than 0.65 and less than 0.8. The variable `mask` will be a Boolean vector with the same size as `x`, i.e, 200 samples. This mask will have samples with values True or False. For each sample of the array `x` that satisfies the condition (`0.65 < x < 0.8`), the value of the corresponding sample of the mask will be True, otherwise it will be False.

When you multiply a Boolean by a number, the Boolean behaves as an integer with values 0 (False) or 1 (True). So the multiplication `mask * 0.03` results in 0.03 where `0.65 < x < 0.8`, and 0 otherwise.

So this code does simply that:

- For `0.65 < x < 0.8` the standard deviation will be 0.06 + 0.03, i.e., 0.09;
- Otherwise the standard deviation will be 0.06