# How to seed scipy.stats.norm.rvs and have it to use the PCG64 BitGenerator?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452737/5722359) provided a brief introduction on `scipy.stats.norm.rv`.

To seed this function, I did the following and got the following results.

```
>>> norm.rvs(size=10, random_state=12345)
array([-0.20470766,  0.47894334, -0.51943872, -0.5557303 ,  1.96578057,
        1.39340583,  0.09290788,  0.28174615,  0.76902257,  1.24643474]
```

**Questions:**

1. For NumPy v1.19, is this function using NumPy's `SeedSequence` or the legacy seeding algorithm to seed the generator? If the former, how do I pass the `child_seeds` of the `SeedSequence` to it?
2. How do I get `scipy.stats.norm.rv` to use `numpy.random.default_rng()` or the BitGenerator (PCG64) instead of the MT19937 BitGenerator. According to [NumPy's documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html?highlight=numpy%20random%20randomstate#numpy.random.RandomState), I understand that `RandomState` refers to NumPy's Legacy Random Generation which is the MT19937 BitGenerator. I did the following and got an exception:

   ```
   >>> from scipy.stats import norm
   >>> from numpy.random import default_rng
   >>> rg = default_rng( 12345 )
   >>> norm.rvs(size=10, random_state=rg)
   ValueError: Generator(PCG64) at 0x7F19E528D228 cannot be used to seed a numpy.random.RandomState instance
   ```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me (`scipy.__version__` is 1.5.0, `numpy.__version__` is 1.19.1.)

Comment: @fuglede Thanks. I was using scipy v1.3.3 and numpy v1.19.1 and encountered the problem. My script worked for scipy v1.5.2 too.